# Base changing algorithm in c++/c

Tags: c++

I have the following function:

```
template <class T>
T c_base (T num,T second, T first = 10)
{
    T res = 0;
    T secnum;
    T bitseed[90];
    int i = 1,k,jump,anex,len;
    if(second==first)
    {
        res = num;
        return (res);
    }
    if(first==10&&second!=10)
    {
        anex = num;
        while(num>0)
        {
            jump = num/second;
            bitseed[i] = num%second;
            num/=second;
            i++;
        }
        if(anex>0)
        {
            for(k=i;k>=1;k--)
            {
                if(k==i&&jump==0) {res = bitseed[k-1]; k--; continue;}
                if(k==i&&jump!=0) {res = jump; continue;}
                res = res*10+bitseed[k];
            }
        }
        return (res);
    }

    if(second==10)
    {
        anex = num;
        len = 1;
        while(anex>=10)
        {
            len *= 10;
            anex/=10;
            i++;
        }
        anex = num;
        if(anex>0)
        {
            for(k=i;k>=1;k--)
            {
                res = res*first+anex/len;
                anex%=len;
                len/=10;
            }
        }
        return (res);
    }

    if(second!=10&&first!=10)
    {
        secnum = c_base <T> (num,10,first);
        res = c_base <T> (secnum,second,10);
        return (res);
    }
}
```

I was wondering how efficient it is (from both speed and memory consumed point of view) and how/if can it be improved. (from the algorithm perspective)

Ps. Explication of function : c_base("number","to-base","from-base"->optional);

Comment: SO is not the place for code review.

Comment: You should think how to do direct conversion from base K to base N without going through base 10 -- perhaps base 2^32 or base 2^64 is needed anyway...

Comment: Since when does C have templates? o.O

Comment: Take this to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you for your suggestion....didn't know that there is a forum special for this :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a lot of confusion here:

- A number doesn't have a base. What do have bases are number **representations**. Both input and output should be number representations (e.g. `std::strings` in C++).
- Why treating base 10 specially? there's nothing really special about it except that by historical accidents most humans today use it. This is totally irrelevant for an algorithm. A special case for power-of-two bases could make sense for technical reasons (because computers use base 2 internally).
- Why doing a double conversion instead of just reading from base `x` and writing to base `y`?

Comment: I did a double conversion because the algorithm i used to change the base works only from base 10 to x and from x to 10. But i will try to make it straight. I have no "excuse" for the other points :)